# как упростить? что бы не писать каждый раз os.system('')?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: code]

[image: как я хочу]
как упростить? что бы не писать каждый раз os.system('')?
у меня написан bat file (3) как легко перенести в python

[image: bat]

Comment: Для начала приложить ваш код текстом и описать желаемый результат. Что значит упростить?

Comment: А вы слышали про списки и циклы? :) Значения в кавычках можно добавить в список. Элементы в списке перебирать в цикле, а в цикле вызывать `os.system(f'Devmanview /disable "{name}"')`, где `name` - переменная в цикле

Comment: сервис `Printer port (LPT1)` повторён два раза.

Answer (score 3):

Создайте функцию, и передавайте ей нужные команды в цикле из списка комманд, из файла, БД, да откуда угодно:

Python:

```
import os

# Список комманд
commands = ['command 1', 'command 2', ]

# Фукция для выполнения комманд
def execute(command):
    os.system(str(command))

# Цикл выполнит все команды из списка
for command in commands:
    execute(command)
```

p.s В данном, простом примере мы храним команды в списке, в котором можем изменять, добавлять, удалять, исправлять нужные команды, больше не вмешиваясь в код.

Comment: можно еще больше упростить, убрав функцию `execute` и написав вместо нее `execute = os.system`. Итог: меньше кода и быстрее работает

Comment: Не нужно привыкать к такому. Так как функция для того и нужна, чтобы ее можно было использовать где угодно, а вносить правки и расширять в одном месте. Если я использую ваш подход в 1000+ местах в проекте, а потом мне понадобится внести правки, например поменять os.system на subprocess, или логировать выполнение или еще что-то, я буду вынужден сделать это в 1000+ местах. Поэтому ваша рекомендация подходит лишь для данного примера не больше. В реальных проектах никто так делать не станет.

Answer (score 2):

Данные надо хранить удобно. Простой текст с именами сервисов проще всего поддерживать. Всё остальное в цикл и код:

```
import os


services = '''
ACPI Processor Aggregator
System Timer
Generic PnP Monitor
'''

for service in services.split('\n'):
    service = service.strip()
    if service:
        os.system(f'Devmanview /disable "{service}"')
```

**P.S.** В коде из строк убираются пробелы - можно делать отступы. Пустые строки пропускаются - многострочный литерал хранит лишние пустые строки в начале и в конце. Кроме того можно разбивать список на группы пустыми строками-разделителями.

Comment: Если пользователь захочет добавить команды в которых нет в начале строки "Devmanview /disable", ему придется править цикл и убирать это оттуда, тогда не будут работать команды которым нужна эта строка в начале, и ему придется править вашу "удобную строку с командами" дописывая в начало каждой строки эту часть. В чем удобство так же непонятно. А если таких команд 1000000+? Писать код нужно универсально, и масштабируемо.